# Fundamental set of solutions for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

Let $a$ and $b$ be distinct positive integers. Prove that $(x^{a}, x^{b})$ cannot be a fundemental set of solutions of any second order ODE of the form

$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$

on the interval $(-1,1)$, where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are continuous functions on $(-1,1)$.

My progress: I managed to obtain functions $p(x)=\frac{1-a-b}{x}$ and $q(x)=\frac{ab}{x^2}$, which are continuous everywhere except zero. Therefore, I am not sure how to continue after this, unsure whether this finishes the problem or not.

Comment: What are $x_a,x_b$? Do you mean $x_a(x)=x^a$? Compute value and derivatives at $x=0$ and consider the corresponding IVP.

Comment: I have computed the derivatives of given fundamental sets, plugged them in the ODE and by solving two equations, I found that $p(x)x=1-a-b$, $q(x)x^2=ab$ should hold. Does it finish the problem?

Comment: If you have $y(0)=y'(0)=0$ in an ODE of the given type, what is the only possible solution?

Comment: The identically zero function, i.e. $y(x) = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $x^a$, $a>0$, we have

$$a(a-1)x^{a-2}+p(x)ax^{a-1}+q(x)x^a=0$$

and
$$\lim_{x\to 0}(a(a-1)+xp(x)+ax^2q(x))=a(a-1)=0,$$ which is only possible with $a=1$.

Comment: Wait, it is given that $x$ lies on the interval $(-1,1)$, how can we use limit in this domain, while it is given that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are continuous on this set.

Comment: @DarkKnight: I thought that $0$ was in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: How do you know that limit of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ exist? If they do not exist, it is unclear whether you can use limit product rule.

Comment: Choose $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ as fractional functions and given limit will fail. Appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: @DarkKnight: how could the limits of $xp(x)$ and $x^2q(x)$ not exist ? (And I don't agree with your last statement.)

Comment: How can you deduce that if $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are continuous on $(-1,1)$, then it will imply the limits of $xp(x)$ and $x^2q(x)$ exist? I am curious because continuity does not conclude the existence of limit. I am terribly sorry if my questions are too ridiculous .

Comment: @DarkKnight: continuous implies bounded.

Comment: But, given domain is not closed interval. How continuity implies boundedness?

Comment: @DarkKnight: grrr, we are talking around zero !

Answer (score 2):

If $0<a<b$, then $b\ge 2$ and thus $y(x)=x^b$ has values $y(0)=y'(0)=0$. However the only solution of an initial value problem for the given DE form with these initial conditions is the zero solution. As $x^b\ne 0$ in general, this gives a contradiction.

Comment: How do you deduce that the initial conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$ imply there is only one solution and that is identically zero function? Apologize if it's stupid question.

Comment: The zero function is a solution and uniqueness applies.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you find identically zero function is a unique solution. I know that the solution of homogenous DE is $y_{h}=c_{1}x^a+c_{2}x^b$. How do you deduce it from this expression?

Comment: Any solution is unique if the ODE satisfies the assumptions of Picard-Lindelöf. And any linear ODE with continuous coefficients does.